# how to check if a PouchDB doc exist or not using an service function on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I'm trying to do an service function that will check if an specific doc exists or not, I have this in my controller

```
if (myService.exist()){
    // doc Exists

} else {
    // doc does NOT Exist

}
```

`myService` has this function:

```
   myService.exist = function(){

        myDB.get('config', function(error, response){
            if (error){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    };
```

but I am missing something (probably regarding the PouchDB promise) because I always get undefined in my controller.

I also tried:

```
    myService.exist = function(){

        myDB.get('appConfig').then( function() {
            return true;
        }).catch(function() {
            return false
        });
    };
```

How can I get this response correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are having is due to the fact that pouchDB's `get` method is returning a promise, so you cannot have the function return a value from inside of the callback function.

In order to accomplish this, you need to have your function return the promise.

```
myService.exist = function(){
    return myDB.get('config');
};
```

This will ensure that you can call the function and apply the `.then` function on the result.  However, this means that your function will be resolved or rejected in the same way as the `get` function, so you would need to change your calling function to something like:

```
myService.exist().then(function () {
    // doc Exists
}).catch(function () {
    // doc does NOT Exist
});
```

If you want your promise to resolve with a `boolean` instead of the document result from pouch, you will need to define a new promise, and return that promise.  I usually use a library such as Q to do this, but depending on your support requirements, you could use the Native Javascript library, and it would look something like:

```
myService.exist = function(){
    return myDB.get('config').then(function () {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }).catch(function () {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    });
};
```

And then your calling function would look like this:

```
myService.exist().then(function (res) {
    if (res) {
        // doc Exists
    } else {
        // doc does NOT Exist
    }
});
```

This would ensure that you can have the promise be resolved no matter what since you only care that the document exists, and you don't want to treat a missing document as an error.

You will not be able to have your function return a boolean value if your function relies on a promise, since that promise would need to be resolved to get your answer, and this takes time.  When your function is complete (Immediately after calling the `get` function, you have not returned anything (since you have your returns in callback functions to be called later.  So your function returns undefined.

Promises are pain at the beginning, but are a very helpful tool once you fully understand them.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Answer (score 1):

I use this in Vue, you can try the following with async function

```
myService.exist = async function(){
    await myDB.get('config')
      .then(function(){ return true;})
      .catch(function() { return false; })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per new `ES7` standards, your myService.exist can look like this,

```
myService.exist = async (id) => myDB.get(id);
```

And while calling this service, use await.

```
try{
    await myService.exist('id');
    //reaching here means it exists. write next part of your code here
}catch(err){
    //means doc doesn't exist
}
```

Don't forget to write `async` in the function enclosing your controller logic.